# Linux Shell Scripting - Regex to Filter Filename with Date in it

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have thousands of files in this naming format:

```
cdr_ABSHCECLUSTER_02_201709072214_987392
```

I am using the batch script below but what I have found is, it will relocate files based on the modified date, not when they actually were created. How can I modify this to pull the year, month from the file name?

Since files can be moved around, I discovered that the files can be put in the wrong directories based on the 'modification date' instead of the creation date.

stat shows options:
access
modified
changed

```
 for dir in /sftphome/*;
 do
    echo "Entering parent directory: " $dir
    cd $dir;
             if [  -d "CDR" ]; then
                    dirpath="$(pwd)/CDR"
                    cd $dirpath

                    echo "Searching CDR directory for files " $dirpath
                    find . -maxdepth 2 -type f |
                            while read file ; do
                                    #Check to see if object is a file or directory. Only copy files.
                                    if [[ ! -d $file ]]; then
                                            year="$(date -d "$(stat -c %y "$file")" +%Y)"
                                            month="$(date -d "$(stat -c %y "$file")" +%b)"

                                            #Create the directories if they don't exist. The -p flag makes 'mkdir' create the parent directories as needed
                                            if [ ! -d "$dirpath/$year/$month" ]; then
                                                    echo "Creating directory structure $dirpath/$year/$month..."
                                                    mkdir -p "$dirpath/$year/$month";
                                                    echo "Directory $dirpath/$year/$month created."
                                            fi

                                            echo "Relocating $dirpath/$file to $dirpath/$year/$month"
                                            cp -p $file "$dirpath/$year/$month"
                                            rm -f $file
                                    fi
                            done
                            echo "Relocation of all files in $dirpath is complete."
             el
```

I would appreciate any insight. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at the shell [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) operators, which can be used to extract parts of a variable using patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one method for populating the `year` and `month` variables from the date stamp in the file name ...

Start with our filename in the variable `file` ...

```
file=cdr_ABSHCECLUSTER_02_201709072214_987392
```

Using the underscore (`_`) as a delimiter, break `file` into separate strings, placing into an array named `ar`; we'll loop through the array just to show the components ...

```
IFS='_' read -ra ar <<< "${file}"
for i in "${!ar[@]}"
do
    echo "ar[${i}] = ${ar[${i}]}"
done

# output from for loop:

ar[0] = cdr
ar[1] = ABSHCECLUSTER
ar[2] = 02
ar[3] = 201709072214
ar[4] = 987392
```

We'll parse `ar[3]` to get our `year` and `month` values ...

```
year=${ar[3]:0:4}     # 4-digit year  = substring from position 0 for 4 characters
mo=${ar[3]:4:2}       # 2-digit month = substring from position 4 for 2 characters
echo "year=${year} , mo=${mo}"

# output from echo command:

year=2017, mo=09
```

But your script wants `month` in `Mmm` format (`date +%b`), so a small adjustment ...

```
# convert our 2-character month to a 3-character 'Mon'th

month=$(date -d "${mo}" +%b)

# confirm our variables:

echo "year=${year} ; month=${month}"

# output from echo command:

year=2017 ; month=Sep
```

At this point we've populated the `year` and `month` variables from the date stamp in the file name, and now you can continue with the rest of your script.

Putting it all together:

```
# once the 'file' variable is populated:

IFS='_' read -ra ar <<< "${file}"
year=${ar[3]:0:4}
mo=${ar[3]:4:2}
month=$(date -d "${mo}" +%b)
```

Answer (score 1):

This script is all you need.

```
find /sftphome/*/CDR -type f -maxdepth 2 | 
    while read file 
    do
        date=`basename "$file" | cut -d_ -f4`
        newdir="$(cut -d/ -f-4 <<< "$file")/${date:0:4}/${date:4:2}"
        mkdir -p "$newdir"
        mv -f "$file" "$newdir"
    done
```

**Edit:**

I just noticed the `%b` date format. If that is a MUST (which I wouldn't recommend as it's hard to sort), then replace the `newdir=...` line with:

```
newdir="$(cut -d/ -f-4 <<< "$file")/$(date -d${date:0:4}-${date:4:2}-01 +%Y/%b)"
```